# Accessing a model variable in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Obviously I am new to Django, because I would assume this is relatively simple.

Lets say in my models.py I created a model "User", with two fields, a "username" and a "email" field. In a form called "UserForm", I want to access a list of all the "username"s in the "User" model. This list would then be used to populate a dropdown menu using Select.

I feel like this should be really easy, and I have been looking for some simple way to do it. I can find lots of ways that aren't all inclusive (ie filter(username = "Joe")), but I can't find one that will list all the users.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you be more specific? where do you want the list to show up? is it a part of the form ?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a ModelChoiceField. Its `queryset` property can be populated from an ORM call, getting you all of the Users. Have a look at the section [Creating Forms from Models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/modelforms/) in the docs for more information.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = # Your model here

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fields['user'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())
```

ForeignKey fields will be automatically shown as ModelChoiceFields, but you can always override the choices if you need.

Comment: Thanks for catching that typo Daniel.

Comment: Sorry if this is dumb, but could you explain the __init__ function? I am assuming that when the form is called, it will be run, and populate the 'user' field with a list of the User objects. The issue is, I am not using the default User from django (mostly cuz i dont know how). How could I do this with a custom User model? Or should I just use the django User?

Comment: That's correct. Nothing says you have to use the default User object from Django. It just depends on what the needs of your application are.

Comment: thanks. Now that I am looking at the User docs, I think that is the way to go =)